# How can I change the default TMUX plugin manager key bindings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

For example, the default binding to install plugins using the TMUX plugin manager is <kbd>prefix + I</kbd>, but say I accidentally overwrite this with another key binding. How can I reset it without killing/restarting the session, or how can I explicitly declare the binding in my `.tmux.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

`set -g @tpm-clean 'u'`

https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm/issues/70

This may help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).